# В чем ошибка в Flutter приложении?

Tags: flutter, dart

Пишу на Flutter. В классе TextButton почему-то возникает ошибка "error: Invalid constant value. (invalid_constant at [untitled2] lib\main.dart:15)", и я не понимаю почему ошибка возникает в строчке `TextButton(onPressed: () {print("Ckliked");}, child: Text("push")),` в месте `() {print("Ckliked");}`.

Кто может объяснить, почему? И кто может еще подсказать, где еще не совсем правильно написано, просто у меня много чего подчеркивается как не совсем правильное, но у человека, по курсу которого я пишу, ничего подобного нет. Если что, пишу по курсу с сайта itProger.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.red,),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("First App"),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: TextButton(onPressed: () {print("Ckliked");}, child: Text("push")),
          // Icon(Icons.settings, size: 45, color: Colors.red,),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Text("Push"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          onPressed: () {
            print("Ckliked");
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### В чем ошибка?

В тексте ошибке сказано что у Вас невалидное значение  для константы.

Когда Вы объявляете какую-либо переменную, как константу Вы обязаны гарантировать что все дочерние объекты также будут неизменными.

В Вашем же случае Вы объявили виджет `Center` **как константу**
внутри которого вы положили:

- *изменяемый* виджет "Кнопка", 
  внутри которой:

  - виджет Текст

которые в свою очередь константами **не являются**.

```dart
const Center(   // <-- это константа
    child: TextButton(  // <-- а это уже НЕ КОНСТАНТА
        onPressed: () {
            print("Ckliked");
        },
        child: Text("push") // <-- и это НЕ КОНСТАНТА
   ),
),
```

### Что делать?

Соответственно, Вы либо убираете `const` перед `Center`

```dart
Center(   
    child: TextButton(  
        onPressed: () => print("Ckliked"),
        child: Text("push") 
   ),
),
```

Либо делаете дочерние элементы также неизменяемыми

```dart
const Center(   
    child: const TextButton(  
        onPressed: () => print("Ckliked"),
        child: const Text("push") 
   ),
),
```